# XCode: "Code Sign on Copy" for resources?

Tags: xcode, codesign

I'm about to upload an app to the Mac App Store. It includes many videos & pictures that I add in a separate build phase to the resource bundle.

Next to the files are check boxes for "Code Sign on Copy". Do I need / should I check them? What is it exactly doing?

[Xcode Build Phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBMgU.png)